# Periodic distribution of prime factors in a recursive sequence?

Tags: number-theory

In the sequence (A052530 - OEIS) $2, 8, 30, 112, ...$ where $a(n)= 4a(n-1) - a(n-2)$, the prime factors demonstrate periodic behavior for the first $28$ elements of the sequence.  For example, $3$ and $5$ are factors of only the elements whose index is a multiple of $3$ (period $3$ within the sequence). On the other hand, $7$ is a prime factor for only the elements whose index is a multiple of $4$ (period $4$). $11$ and $19$ have period $5$, $13$ has period $6$, $41$ and $71$ both have period $7, 97$ has period $8, 17$ has period $9$ and so on.

It really surprised me that the first few primes behaved like this, even for the short span of the sequence that I was able to check. **My question is, do all of the primes have periodic behavior within this sequence?** Has periodicity of prime factors been observed before in recursive sequences (references)?

Here is my conjecture: If $n$ is the index of the sequence and $k$ is a natural number, then there is a prime of the form $2kn +1$ or $2kn-1$ that is a factor of the $n$th element with a period $n$ within the sequence. Take $41$ and $71$, which first show up as factors of the $7$th element $5822$. They are also factors of the $14$th, $21$st and $28$th elements. $41 = 2(3)(7)-1$ and $71 = 2(5)(7)+1.$ This general observation seems to hold for at least the primes up to $23$, albeit for a small sample of the sequence.

If the conjecture is true, then a natural outcome is an algorithm for finding large primes, ie. take a prime index of the sequence, and then find prime factors of this element by successively dividing $2kn \pm 1$. Repeat using the highest prime output as an index again, and so on.

Bob Tivnan

Comment: Did you try reducing $a(n)=4a(n−1)−a(n−2)$ modulo $p$ ? here $a(n)-4a(n-1)+a(n-2)= 0$ is inversible modulo $p$, that is knowing $a(n),a(n -1) \bmod p$ you can find $a(n-2) \bmod p$, and so $a(n) \bmod p$ is periodic since the beginning. In general, with such a recurrence $a(n) = f(a(n-1),\ldots,a(n-k))$ it only ends up being periodic $\bmod p$, but not necessarily from the beginning.

Comment: I think I understand you. Any term a(n) has a prime factor p iff a(n) mod p = 0. Rearranging in mod p,  a(n-2) = 4a(n-1) - a(n) mod p, which is simply the involution of the original recursive function. So, it turns out that the forward progression of terms mod p can be shown to have opposites mod p working backwards ...-a(n+2)mod p, -a(n+1)mod p, a(n)mod p, a(n+1)mod p, a(n+2)mod p...If any forward term a(n+k) mod p = 0, then there must be another term -a(n+k) mod p = 0. This will continue ad infinitum in the forward direction, but has a limit backwards since the terms are positive.